# Passing file content into memory is faulty

Tags: c, function, file

I am wondering why while I think I make the function call to load appropriately,
it seems that fread cannot read into my chunk of memory correctly and so it creates a segmentation fault[in load function]!Please point me to the right approach

The [link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/BJiHlFwUZ) to the code is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

bool load(FILE* file, char** content, size_t* length);

int main()
{
    // opens file
    FILE * file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    // initialises variables 
    char* content;
    size_t length;

    // sending arguments to load function
    bool receive = load(file, &content, &length);

    // debugging content
    printf("values of content: %s\n", content);

    // debugs length

    printf("values of content: %zu\n", length);

    // closes file
    fclose(file);

    // for success
    return 0;
}

bool load(FILE* file, char** content, size_t* length)
{

    {

    // proof checking for the existence of file
    if (file == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

    // perusing to end of file   
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    // for approximation of size of file    
    size_t len = ftell(file);

    // returns cursor to beginning of file  
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // apportions memory on heap for content of file
    * content = (char *) malloc (len + 1);

    // memory error checking

    if(*content == NULL)
    {
        printf("It's unfortunate\n");

    }
    // to read into content     
    fread(* content, sizeof(char), len, file);

    // null terminates content
    (* content)[len] = 0;

    // debugs content    
    printf(" content contains %s\n", * content);

    // debugs length    
    * length = len;

    printf(" length is %d\n", * length);

    // if success 
    return true;

    }

    // if fail 
    return false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly into the question instead of linking to it. While the link do contains your code, it might go stale in the future.

Comment: although I have to say that this link is nice, a real IDE where I can see the code and debug it etc. - I know it will disappear etc. but even so is makes answering very easy

Comment: well the most obvious error is that if `load` returns false you simply carry on. And you never check that fopen worked either

Comment: DWon't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. And don't add a space after the dereference operator; write readable code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check that the file opened OK

```
  FILE * file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if(file == NULL)
  {
      perror("failed to open file: ");
      exit(1);
  }
```

Secondly your load function returns false of it fails, but you dont check it. Do

```
 bool receive = load(file, &content, &length);
 if(!receive)
 {
     fprintf(stderr, "failed to read file");
     exit(1);
 }
```

in load you do

```
  if(*content == NULL)
    {
        printf("It's unfortunate\n");

    }
```

but carry on any way. You should do

```
 if(*content == NULL)
    {
        printf("It's unfortunate\n");
        return false;
    }
```

In general you are not checking the return of any function you call, fseek,ftell,fread,.... You should not be surprised when your program fails. Yes its a boring slog, but thats just the way it is in C land